# Function pointer with some parameters set

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

How can I create a function pointer to a function where some parameters are set to be fixed upon the definition.

Here is an example what I mean:

Let's say I have the function

```
int add (int n, int m) {
     return n+m;
}
```

and the function pointer type

```
typedef int (*increaser)(int);
```

What I want is a pointer to the function `add` which fixes the first parameter to 1 and leaves the second paramenter open. Something along the lines of

```
increaser f = &add(1,x);
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Write a wrapper..

Comment: C does not have closures.

Comment: I wouldn't call the function type `increaser`. To me, it is rather an `int_unary_operator`, as functions implementing this signature can very well do something completely different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I want is a pointer to the function add which fixes the first parameter to 1 and leaves the second paramenter open.

There is no such thing in C.  The closest you can come is to create a wrapper function and make a pointer to that:

```
int add1(int x) {
    return add(1, x);
}

increaser f = &add1;
```

If you don't need a pointer to the function then you can use a macro:

```
#define increaser(x) add(1, (x))
```

Answer (score 1):

C does not support doing this directly. In C++ there is std::function and bind which can achieve this however.

None the less for a pure C solution the closest you can reasonably get is defining a new function that calls add like:

```
int increment(int input) {
    return add(1, input);
}
```

Then you can do:

```
increaser f = &increment;
```